# Batch file to move a file from source in a text file to multiple folders in another text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to move/copy a file (or some files) from a text file (including full path names) to multiple folders from another text file including full destination full paths. This is my batch file but does not work somehow.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (source.txt) do xcopy  /y  /d  (destinations.txt) "%%a\"
```

*source.txt* includes full path of the file. Extension is just a sample; it's not a document nor a picture.

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\move1.txt
```

*destinations.txt* includes full path of the destination folders (no subfolders)

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\d1
C:\Users\Username\Documents\d2
```

Where am I wrong with the batch code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your syntax for `xcopy` is wrong. See [Xcopy - Copy files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html). And you have to read the contents of `destinations.txt` with another (nested) `for` loop.

Comment: You need another nested for command to read the destination text file.

Comment: Thank you DavidPostill and @Squashman I'll take them into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a second `for loop` nested within the statement to check for the destination of the output *text file*.

**From Batch:**

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (source.txt) do (for /f "delims=" %%b in (destinations.txt) do (xcopy "%%a" "%%b" /y))
```

**From CMD:**

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (source.txt) do (for /f "delims=" %b in (destinations.txt) do (xcopy "%a" "%b" /y))
```

For more info on the commands, type the following into a console

- `xcopy /?`
- `for /?`

Comment: @Murray Yeah np!